# Shopify CLI cannot pull font files and won't display font

Tags: css, fonts, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

When pulling a theme from shopify, I get this error:

```
┏━━ Pulling theme files from theme (#120391204918) on mysite.myshopify.com        
┃ ERROR get assets/1618247382_0.jpg: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
┃ ERROR get assets/1619067170_0.jpg: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
┃ ERROR get assets/1619072019_0.jpg: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
┃ ERROR get assets/AT-Surt-DemiBold.otf: "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
┃ ERROR get assets/AT-Surt-DemiBold.eot: "\xC6" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
┃ ERROR get assets/AT-Surt-DemiBold.woff: "\xD8" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
┃ ERROR get assets/AT-Surt-DemiBold.woff2: "\xBF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
┃ ERROR get assets/AT-Surt-Regular.eot: "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
┃ ERROR get assets/AT-Surt-Regular.otf: "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
┃ ERROR get assets/AT-Surt-Regular.woff: "\xA4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
...
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ (114.0s) ━━━
√ Theme pulled successfully
```

I don't know why it errors like this, the theme runs okay on local using `shopify theme serve` but the problem is, it won't display the font on my local dev environment. I also tried pushing it to shopify hoping it will render properly online but it won't

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a workaround at least:

It is not possible to pull fonts from shopify to local. I think that is by purpose, because they dont want you to upload fonts other then those they provide. They want you to use a CDN.

So either you are using Adobe Typekit, Font Awesome oder Google Fonts or some other font library which has its own CDN you can use. If so you can get your link there, for example I want to use the Google Font "Alata" which is not provided in Shopify. So I went to Google Fonts, got me the link to Google CDN and inserted this at the top of my custom CSS file. Works!

[google fonts cdn usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HcEL.png)

Or if you have a font that is not available on a CDN already you can host it somewhere else yourself or use a CDN service (maybe cloudflare?) to do so. I haven't tried to do that but I'm sure its possible and there are tutorials for that over the internet.

If you're running a international website I would recommend not to host fonts on your own server, but on a CDN, as it will likely slow down your page.

If somebody figures this out it would be nice to share a little how-to here ...